# How to reuse a (static) function between two classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance, static-methods

I want to reuse a function in two classes.

The function doesn't take any class related parameter ( i.e. self is not accessed).

Because of its independence, I want to move it outside the class definition to make it available for "future usages". The "future usages" mainly takes place in similar classes like class C().

I also want to know how should I structure the code, if the "future usages" take place all over the project.

We have the following structure:

```py
Class A(): # in file class_a.py
    def static_func(pose1, pose2):
        pass

Class B(): # in another python file called class_b.py
    def static_func(pose1, pose2):
        """
        the same function as in class A
        """
        pass
Class C(): # future usage
    # want to use the static_func as well
```

What is the best way to reuse the "static_func" in the two classes?

Comment: This is not a staticmethod. This is just an incorrectly defined instance method. The classes aren't meant to inherit from each other? If they were staticmethods Then simply call `A.static_func` in `B.static_func`... Note, static methods aren't very useful in Python. Why don't you just use a regular function? As an aside, you probably shouldn't be creating modules like `class_x.py`... python modules aren't meant to simply store a single class (usually). Python != Java

Comment: Why not export the 'static_fuction' to external file then import it?

Comment: Can you clarify your problem? If it’s a function, you don’t have to do anything special to use it in more than one place.

Answer (score 2):

If that function is just called from the classes themselves and doesn't need to form part of the *public interface* of the class: don't make it a method at all. Just let it be a function independent of any class.

If that function *is* part of the public interface of the class, i.e. you expect other code to do `a = A(); a.static_func()`, then use a mixin:

```
class FuncMixin:
    @staticmethod
    def static_func(...):
        ...

class A(FuncMixin):
    ...

class B(FuncMixin):
    ...
```